# Why is there just one person allowed to close off a question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a reasonable question here - [How to allocate memory properly on a windows server running XAMPP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/849601/how-to-allocate-memory-properly-on-a-windows-server-running-xampp?noredirect=1#comment1090419_849601)

What does this close reason mean and how do things get closed with one vote?

Comment: _"I asked a reasonable question..."_ No. No you didn't. Thus your question got closed. Case closed! ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ

Comment: The best answer you could probably get to your question is: to resolve your performance issues, start looking at moving away from XAMPP and setting up a proper LAMP setup... You'll have a very hard time finding volunteers who want to help you with the performance of a production XAMPP setup. And whoever does volunteer information probably didn't know what they were getting into when poking the bees nest that is one click setups.

Comment: @Wesley - <edited> why don't you explain why it wasn't reasonable.  I have years of hosting/server background.  I do not have years supporting crap environments like XAMPP or converting them thus I asked before I go off on my own (looking for the easiest way of course).   You are missing the piece that this is co-owned with a vendor and not everything can be perfectly controlled. <edited>

Comment: @blankip I can sympathize with you that you're stuck in a tough spot here. Truly I can. You're being asked to put lipstick on a pig. That fact, though, doesn't mean that XAMPP is on-topic because you're being forced to use it. It's still, even in your situation, a system that is wholly unsuitable for production use. Now, as to why it's not suitable for prod usage, see this QA: https://serverfault.com/q/453617/20815

Comment: @blankip I will also caution you to not stoop to personal attacks, nor to making assumptions about the knowledge or experience of those you're interacting with.

Comment: @blankip Because that would be a gross duplication of effort. What is and is not on topic has already been explained many times within this thread, and within the FAQ / Help system for the site.

Answer (score 10):

> What does this close reason mean and how do things get closed with one
>   vote?

The close reason is brutally clear. Additionally, Sven gave you more detail in a comment:

> Don't use XAMPP as production system. Ever. This is purely a dev tool

If you need more detail on the reasoning behind this, check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/453617/why-not-use-a-wamp-stack).

As to your other question, questions can be closed in three main ways:

1. Moderators can close any question single-handedly.
2. Non-moderator with a [gold tag badge](https://serverfault.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=gold) can single-handedly close questions in that tag.
3. Five non-moderator community members can vote to close the question.

In your case Sven, a moderator, saw fit to close your question. I agree with his assessment and action.

Comment: Who says XAMPP is a dev tool?  It is on thousands of production environments world wide.  I didn't choose to use it (it was made for me) and agree it has issues but since it is used on productions servers - EVERYWHERE - I doubt your ability to answer this question.  Please show me that XAMPP is not used in production environments.   I am not sure you or the few other mods that agree are the people who make definitions for what is prod and what isn't.  The site's FAQs suggest it is a good question so maybe you should get that changed too.   Unreal.

Comment: @blankip I will give you two quotes from the XAMPP website. 1) "XAMPP is the most popular PHP development environment" and 2) "The goal of XAMPP is to build an easy to install distribution for developers to get into the world of Apache." Do you need any more evidence than that?

Comment: Furthermore: I couldn't care less if XAMPP is used in production. Whether or not something is used has absolutely no bearing on whether or not it *should* be used. Windows Server 2003 is still used on hundreds of thousands of servers around the world, in spite of the fact that it's EOL and is not receiving security updates. Does the fact that it's in use make it a good idea? Absolutely not.

Comment: I can assure you that there is consensus on this issue not only among the moderators here, but also among the community in general. Evidence of that is visible in the voting on this exact question and answer. Look, I know this wasn't the answer you wanted, but this was the risk you took when asking on a site that values doing things right and building secure, well-supported, reliable systems. XAMPP and the other one-click installers don't fit into that picture.

Comment: @blankip Do you need more clarification? I genuinely want to help you understand what happened here. We're not a bunch of militant power-hungry jerks. We all participate here because we have a desire to help people. Sometimes, though, helping people well means telling them things that they don't want to hear. I believe that's what happened with your question.

Comment: I don't think you guys get it.  I would never set up a server like this.  It is being used in production for a large scale suite of sites.  I took over managing this - which is co-owned by a vendor.  What the site is assuming is that the people asking the questions have full control.  I am asking what can I do given the constraints I have not "tell me how bad my environment is and refuse to talk unless I do things the perfect way".  ... cont.

Comment: cont...   It is akin to someone asking how to install some door in the DIY and then they say they won't answer because that brand of door isn't good enough quality.   Well that is perfectly fine to comment about the quality of the door and telling them that they are dumb for using the door but they would still tell you how to install it as best as it could be.  What is more perplexing and quite frankly idiotic is why there would be a tag "XAMPP" when all XAMPP questions are refused.

Comment: Yes, we do actually assume that question askers do have full control of the systems they're asking about. If they don't, they're *users* of the system, not administrators. Server Fault is not like most other SE sites, in that it is by professionals, for professionals. We've collectively drawn a line in the sand, and have agreed that XAMPP questions are off-topic. If you want to try and sway community opinion on this, you're always free to post a meta question with your reasoning.

Comment: If the community decides after hearing your rationale that they do want to allow these questions, I'll do it gladly. Until then, though, you'll just need to come to grips with the fact that your question is off-topic.

Comment: Re. the existence of the tag [tag:xampp]: Not all questions regarding this product are necessarily off-topic. I can imagine questions regarding how to efficently install this product for multiple *developers* in an automated fashion. This would't be considered the same as questions regarding to do this for products like MS Office and the like.

Comment: What is that "gold tag badge"? Could not find it with your link.